# how to pass method ref from main controller to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a function **getData** defined in main controller that I would like to use in my directive. I tried including the function in scope but seems I am still missing something or doing it wrong.

[plunker link to my testcase](http://plnkr.co/edit/QTin1ozCAgyuoyTrQ4Y0?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive("position", function(){
   return {
       restrict:'A',
       template: "<tr><td ng-repeat='(key,value) in position'>{{getData(key,value,$index)}}</td></tr>",
       replace: false,
       scope: {
         position: '=',
         getData: '&'
       }
   };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.positions = [{ Name: "Quarterback", Code: "QB" },
                       { Name: "Wide Receiver", Code: "WR" }
                      ]; 
   $scope.getData=function(key , value,index){
       return '|' + value + '|';
   }
});
```

Comment: Your code, `getData: '&'`, means execute the expression in the `getData` **attribute** on the parent scope. This means `getData` should be passed in an attribute for that to work. It is also possible, however, to refer to it through `$parent` inside the directive with `scope.$parent.getData`, or to remove the isolated scope and use `scope.getData`. See [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead

```
{{$parent.$parent.getData(key,value,$index)}}
```

The first `$parent` is to reach the parent scope of the repeater defined in the directive. The 2nd `$parent` is to reach the parent scope of the directive.

Answer (score 2):

When using the Isolate $scope and "&", it means you are going to pass in a reference to the method from the HTML. You can keep your $scope definition on your directive. For example:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in positions" position="item" get-data="getData(item.Name, item.Code, $index)"></tr>
</table>
```

Here, I am passing in get-data to your directive (notice the difference, we are snake cased in the HTML where we are referenced as getData in the $scope). Then you can reference this instance of getData in your template.

Comment: here $index is the index for ng-repeat on <tr>. I want to pass the index for ng-repeat on <td> defined in directive template.

Comment: may be its sufficient to just pass get-data="$scope.getData" and then call this method from with in the directive template. will try that. ( as opposed to calling the getData method right in <tr> )